# How to implement dynamic roles and rights in Express Js?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, authorization, roles

I need to implement an authentication system where a super admin can create multiple different roles with different rights for users. That is, not a system with a set number of roles, but have the option to create as many roles with different combination of rights as the superadmin wants, and then assign them to new users. Also with the option of editing these roles, deleting them etc. I'm fairly new at Node Js. Is this something hard to implement? Are there any articles/videos I can read/watch, to start understanding the process? Where do I start? I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking about [Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control). I have actually implemented this in Node.js before, feel free to checkout how I implemented it here: https://github.com/JLCarveth/nodeblog.

It's relatively simple. You need a table for tracking roles. Each role has 0 or more *permissions*. These permissions can be comma-separated strings, or IDs referencing a permissions table. Each user is then assigned a role.

Each route is protected with a middleware that specifies the needed permissions. If a user accesses this route, check that they have the necessary permissions and continue, reject if not.